# Replace specific file inside Zip archive without extracting the whole archive in Java

Tags: java, zip4j

I'm trying to get a specific file inside a Zip Archive, extract it, Encrypt it, and then get it back inside the archive replacing the origial one.

here's what I've tried so far..

```
public static boolean encryptXML(File ZipArchive, String key) throws ZipException, IOException, Exception {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ZipArchive);
    List<FileHeader> fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();
    for (FileHeader fh : fileHeaderList)
    {
        if (fh.getFileName().equals("META-INF/file.xml"))
        {
            Path tempdir = Files.createTempDirectory("Temp");
            zipFile.extractFile(fh, tempdir.toString());
            File XMLFile = new File(tempdir.toFile(), fh.getFileName());

            // Encrypting XMLFile, Ignore this part

            // Here, Replace the original XMLFile inside ZipArchive with the encrypted one <<<<<<<<

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I stuck at the replacing part of the code is there anyway I can do this without having to extract the whole Zip Archive?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo!

I'm able to do it that way

```
ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
parameters.setIncludeRootFolder(true);
zipFile.removeFile(fh);
zipFile.addFolder(new File(tempdir.toFile(), "META-INF"), parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you as you are using a different library but the solution in [ZT Zip](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip) would be the following.

```
ZipUtil.unpackEntry(new File("/tmp/demo.zip"), "foo.txt", new File("foo.txt"));
// encrypt the foo.txt
ZipUtil.replaceEntry(new File("/tmp/demo.zip"), "foo.txt", new File("foo.txt"));
```

This will unpack the `foo.txt` file and then after you encrypt it you can replace the previous entry with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ZipFilesystem (as of Java 7) as explained in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to read/write within a zip file as if it were its own file system.

However, on my machine, this unpacks and re-packs the zip file under the hood anyway (tested with 7 and 8). I am not sure if there is a way to reliably change zip files like you describe.